# How to get tooltips working with dynamic array in vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to make tooltips from a dynamically generated array.

https://codepen.io/sneaky666/pen/BXrjOp?&editable=true&editors=101

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid class="text-center">
      <v-layout
        flex
        justify-space-between
        wrap
      >
        <v-flex xs12 class="mt-12">
           <v-tooltip v-for="item in getData()" v-model="item.show" top>
             <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                 <v-btn @click="item.show = !item.show">{{item.data.name}}</v-btn>
              </template>
            <span>{{item.data.name}}</span>
           </v-tooltip>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      actions : [{name:"a"},{name:"b"},{name:"c"},{name:"d"}],
      show: false,
    }
  },
  methods : {
    getData : function() {
      return this.actions.concat({name:"e"}).map(function(x) {
        return {data : x, show:false};
      });
    }
  }
})
```

but this doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work because **data returned in a function is not reactive**.

If your original data array for some reason doesn't have the "show" property in each object, you have to first, add the `show` property to your data (for example on the created hook), then bind the v-for loop to data rather than to your method.

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid class="text-center">
      <v-layout
        flex
        justify-space-between
        wrap
      >
        <v-flex xs12 class="mt-12">
           <v-tooltip v-for="item in actions" v-model="item.show" top>
             <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                 <v-btn @click="item.show = !item.show">{{ item.name }}</v-btn>
              </template>
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
           </v-tooltip>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  created() {
    this.appendShow();
  },
  data () {
    return {
      actions : [{ name:"a"},{name:"b"},{name:"c"},{name:"d"}],
      show: true,
    }
  },
  methods : {
    appendShow : function() {
      let vm = this;
      this.actions.push({ name: "e" })
      this.actions.forEach(action => {
        vm.$set(action, 'show', false)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Working example here:
https://codepen.io/CodingDeer/pen/XvEXOo?editors=1010

Comment: yes, but the problem is, I need it working on the transformed array which is why I put the `concat` part. How can I make the transformed array reactive?

Comment: Sure - I added that part into the `appendShow` function. This adds your extra object into the array and then makes it reactive.